# How to Set Up Multiple projects in one IP in nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Hi Everyone i need help with this, I've already set up nginx + php and it works great, faster than apache, my problem is how to setup a multiple projects in one IP? i'm using codeigniter and I've follow the nginx wiki unfortunately i can't display what's in the controller e.i: `http://192.168.0.2/testcode/welcome` but if i browse the base url i.e: `http://192.168.0.2/testcode/` it displays the welcome controller, I'm trying to achieve like this, for example PC1 is my server, and PC2 is the user so I'm going to access like this `http://192.168.0.2/testcode/` and `http://192.168.0.2/testcode/` same ip but different project.

Comment: same url different page ?

Comment: Please clarify. Avoid unnecessary information but include everything relevant to your problem.

Comment: sorry about that my bad, I'm trying to achieve a different project in one host, I've setup a local server and I'm gonna access it by IP/Project Name, how do i setup my nginx.conf and the host file in windows.?

Comment: Do you think about something like this here: http://serverfault.com/questions/218818/nginx-projects-in-subfolders